# Flutter Integration in android Studio issue

Tags: android-studio, flutter

While integrating Flutter in Android studio getting error as * Error running Gradle: Unable to download needed Android SDK components, as the following licenses have not been accepted: Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2, Android SDK Platform 27  To resolve this, please run the following command in a Terminal: flutter doctor --android-licenses

Comment: What's the result of `flutter doctor --android-licenses`? I have seen this issue mentioned a few times recently, but don't know if something was suggested how to fix it.

Comment: sdkmanager --version failed: 1 this is the result

Comment: In menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager > SDK tools" are there any "Update available" items?

Comment: yes, Android SDK platform tools from 27.0.0 to 27.0.1

Comment: I this on Windows? Are you using a non-standard shell?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14942#issuecomment-369319232 might help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]
Problem was with sdk path in local.properties. By default its pointing to different location. It works for me when change android sdk home dir in sdk.dir